# Failing to webscrape in r, using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape this page: https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P171821

In particular, I want to extract the Associated Projects id (in this case it is P145196).

I'm using rvest package.

I've tried the following code, but this has resulted in an empty vector.

```
library(rvest)

simple <- read_html("https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/project-detail/P171821") %>%
      html_nodes(".ng-tns-c2-0") %>%
      html_text()

> simple
character(0)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: click view source in your browser. do you see ng-tns-c2-0 there? I don't

Comment: No, I don't either. I used Developer Tools (Ctrl+shift+I) to inspect the item. This is how I found the node.

Comment: Weird; I've tried searching the view source, but can't find most of the contents of the page. How is that possible?

Comment: `rvest` can only read the page source. What you see in your browser was probably generated with javascript. `rvest` cannot run javascript. If you need to interact with page that use javascript, then you'll need to use something like RSelenium.

Comment: the site runs JS, to fetch data to populate the page with. You need to either make R run js on that page (hard), or figure out what goes on and reverse engineer the process (likely easier). Tip: watch the network tab in developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it comes from this json url:

```r
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- fromJSON("https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects?format=json&fl=*&id=P171821&apilang=en")
json_data$projects[["P171821"]]$parentprojid
```

Output:

```
> json_data$projects[["P171821"]]$parentprojid
[1] "P145196"
```

You can easily update that url to query other project ids

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks. I'm a bit new to R and am wondering how to automatise this. Suppose that I have a dataframe whereby column A has project IDs, and column B has URL for the corresponding project. Now I would like to create a col C that would scrape the projID of the parent project. How could I do this? I will include a sample data set in my original post. Could you have a look?

Comment: You should start by asking this in a new question

Comment: I've asked a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391080/how-to-automate-webscraping). Could you please have a look?

Comment: I saw it, prepared the answer, but it got deleted

Comment: My apologies... I undeleted the question. Could you still post the answer? I thought that it received no attention...